# Erlang Hello World using Bazel as a build system

Tags: erlang, bazel

I want to build an Erlang hello world example using [rules_erlang](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rules_erlang) on Ubuntu 22.04.

My setup looks like this:

*BUILD.bazel*

```
load("@rules_erlang//:erlang_app.bzl", "erlang_app", "test_erlang_app")
load("@rules_erlang//:xref.bzl", "xref")
load("@rules_erlang//:dialyze.bzl", "dialyze", "plt")
load("@rules_erlang//:ct.bzl", "ct_suite", "assert_suites")

APP_NAME = "hello_world"
APP_VERSION = "0.1.0"

erlang_app(
    app_name = APP_NAME,
    app_version = APP_VERSION,
)
```

*src/hello_world.erl*

```
-module(hello_world).
-compile(export_all).


hello() ->
    io:format("hello world~n").
```

*WORKSPACE.bazel*

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "af87959afe497dc8dfd4c6cb66e1279cb98ccc84284619ebfec27d9c09a903de",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.2.0/bazel-skylib-1.2.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.2.0/bazel-skylib-1.2.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")

bazel_skylib_workspace()

http_archive(
    name = "rules_erlang",
    sha256 = "5e59800ecc786d5375951028c959c6e6275c94eff2a52f5d53ccb1ad8b2ea20a",
    strip_prefix = "rules_erlang-3.8.4",
    urls = ["https://github.com/rabbitmq/rules_erlang/archive/refs/tags/3.8.4.zip"],
)

load(
    "@rules_erlang//:rules_erlang.bzl",
    "erlang_config",
    "rules_erlang_dependencies",
)

erlang_config()

rules_erlang_dependencies()

load("@erlang_config//:defaults.bzl", "register_defaults")

register_defaults()
```

The code can also found [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/hello_world/Erlang).

When I execute `bazel build //...` I get

> ERROR:
> /home/vertexwahn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vertexwahn/b5f945f94177a8ffa6ac0f7108dfc1cd/external/erlang_config/external/BUILD.bazel:12:16:
> Validating otp at /usr failed: (Exit 1): bash failed: error executing
> command /bin/bash -c ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
>
> Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and
> retain the sandbox build root for debugging Erlang version mismatch
> (Expected UNKNOWN, found 24.2.1)

Any hints to get this working are welcome!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your code in a repo or pastebin.

Comment: @2240 https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/hello_world/Erlang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run it, you can declare a `shell` rule in your BUILD.bazel, for instance:

```
load("@rules_erlang//:shell.bzl", "shell")
shell(
    name = "repl",
    deps = [":erlang_app"],
    extra_erl_args = ["-eval", "'hello_world:hello()'"],
)
```

and then you could bazel `run :repl`.

Or, you could use an `escript` rule if you change `hello_world.erl` so that it exports `main/1` instead of `hello`:

```
load("@rules_erlang//:escript.bzl", "escript_archive")
escript_archive(
    name = "hello_world",
    app = ":erlang_app",
)
```

`hello_world.erl`:

```
-module(hello_world).
-export([main/1]).


main(_) ->
    io:format("hello world~n").
```

and run with `bazel run :hello_world`

Answer (score 1):

```bash
bazel build //... --sandbox_debug
```

gave me

```bash
compile: warnings being treated as errors
hello_world.erl:2:2: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
```

With `-export([hello/0]).` instead of `-compile(export_all).` it works

```erlang
-module(hello_world).
-export([hello/0]).


hello() ->
    io:format("hello world~n").
```

```bash
❯ bazel build //...
INFO: Analyzed 3 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 3 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0,326s, Critical Path: 0,25s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

Comment: One still reaming question is how can I run now the hello_world program? `bazel run //:erlang_app` does not work - any ideas?